# Extract data from text files and make a list from them C#

Tags: c#

Having trouble figuring this out.

I have to read text files with data and want to convert each of them into an array.

DataList

```
dataOne
dataTwo
dataThree
etc.....
```

ItemList

```
listOne
listTwo
listThree
etc.....
```

so read the Items and store them in a list

```
List<string> dataList = new List<string>();
List<string> itemList = new List<string>();
```

Then `Console.WriteLine` the list

```
Console.WriteLine(dataList[0] + itemList[0]);
```

I have been trying to use `StreamReader` to input the text files, but it doesn't seem to add them to a array

```
string dataListFile = @"..\..\FileIOExtraFiles\DataFieldsLayout.txt";
            StreamReader dataFile = new StreamReader(dataListFile);
```

Comment: Where in code are you storing your data from the file into your containers?

Comment: to display it to the console

Comment: Can you provide us with the code you tried to read in the files with?

Comment: not sure if I'm doing this right, Once I import the text files. How would I add them into a List<string> or would it be best into a String[] array

Comment: Did you see _How best to read a File into List<string>_ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6904401/how-best-to-read-a-file-into-liststring

Comment: what @ydoow suggested work. Now that I have them in an array I will just need to loop each to display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx

```
string path = @"..\..\FileIOExtraFiles\DataFieldsLayout.txt";
string[] dataList = File.ReadAllLines(path);
```

Comment: Thanks, that is working but I had to use string[] instead of List.

Comment: Right, I've corrected the type. Feel free to accept the answer if it's working for you.