# Best C# Method to access contents of a text file

Tags: c#, string, file, dictionary, file-read

I am starting to move from `VB6` to `C#`. Although I am a experienced programmer (40+ Years) often it is knowing the newer constructs that are the big help rather than diligently translating line by line.
Out company receives orders by text file which consist of a list of lines.

```
XXX=param1;param2
YYY=param1;param2
```

In VB6 I have created a very complex string class for searching, extracting, updating, adding, deleting, and inserting these lines.

Does C# offer an already existing construct or will I need to write my own.  The Dictionary construct looks good but I am concerned re the number of values, as well as if there is a way that I can import the file in one go without having to read it line by line.

Comment: File.ReadLines().  Then split each line on the ‘;’ character

Comment: @maccettura I removed my comment

Comment: @Ajay2707 read my mind about using a List<T>. With a list you have built-in methods to perform further actions on the content as well.

Comment: How big is you input text file?  Very large files you probably want to read line by line so you do not use lots of memory.  I've been programming for 40 years and nothing has really changed in parsing text files.  Some people use Regex put it is as efficient and doesn't handle inputs that have lots of different formats.  I sometimes use Regex to parse one line into separate parameters.

Answer (score 1):

No, C# doesn't offer this kind of things, you'll need to write your own file parser (probably like the one you already have in VB6).

I don't think the Dictionary will help you here (unless I didn't understand your file structure), dictionaries are for Key-Value pairs (so it's 2 values per entry) but you seem to have plain params (meaning that your entries don't look like key value pairs).

It would be much easier for you to just create 1-2 classes to do the parsing using mainly:

- `File.ReadAllLines` to read the text files and get an array of lines.
- `line.Split(';')` to get the parameters of each line (assuming you foreach the lines).

Comment: Many thanks for the information. At max there are 300 lines so I gues it is back to using line by line translation :)

Answer (score 1):

You are not mention the C# version, @jonskeet mention in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8037070/whats-the-fastest-way-to-read-a-text-file-line-by-line) about `File.ReadLines`,

> If you're using .NET 4, simply use File.ReadLines which does it all
>   for you. I suspect it's much the same as yours, except it may also use
>   FileOptions.SequentialScan and a larger buffer (128 seems very small).

Based on the above answer I search that there is option to convert file result to list and I got the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6904401/how-best-to-read-a-file-into-liststring), so after converting you use linq too.

```
List<string> allLinesText = File.ReadAllLines(fileName).ToList()
```

Comment: Why use ReadLines() and then immediately call ToList()?  Either perform some processing on the resulting IEnumerable from ReadLines() or just call File.ReadAllLines(). There is a difference (IEnumerable Vs List)

Comment: .ToList will convert to array result to list, see in the @Rama result in second links.

Comment: I was mistaken. ReadAllLines() returns an Array. Its still weird to not use ReadAllLines() if you’re not doing any processing on the IEnumerable though.