# asp.net MVC Seed a database from a .TXT file with code first (over 10000 words)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

i want to seed the db from a text file where on each row i have a word(aprox 70000)
ex: word1(next line)
word2(next line)
word3(next line)

i'm guessing i have to use the seed method like i add something else for example

```
protected override void Seed(BabyStore.DAL.StoreContext context)
 {
 var categories = new List<Category>
 {
 new Category { Name = "Clothes" },
 new Category { Name = "Play and Toys" },
 new Category { Name = "Feeding" },
 new Category { Name = "Medicine" },
 new Category { Name= "Travel" },
 new Category { Name= "Sleeping" }
 };
 categories.ForEach(c => context.Categories.AddOrUpdate(p => p.Name, c));
 context.SaveChanges();
```

the table would be something like words. so i would have i guess a table with 70000 words. so i need to read the file and upload those words to be a name for each entry in db?(this is my own thinking but i do't kniow how to do it)

my question is how can i use a text file to seed here? or do i have to do it in another way?(code first) Thank you

Comment: depending on your db, you can simply import the file directly. no coding needed.

Comment: I don't agree this question is a duplicate. OP is not asking how to read a file, he is asking how to bulk insert.

Comment: @shai it's a DB inside a visual studio folder, i created all using code first,locally in the folder and i'm trying to do it this way. i remember trying some time ago with sql directly, which is not very complicated but then i had a separate DB in sql server

Comment: well good luck getting a response now

Comment: i don't know in that regard, i'm sorry. yeah, not sure why this question was closed.

Comment: You use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54456887/578411) and then use `foreach(var line in lines) categories.Add(new Category { Name = line });`.

Comment: that was an example, i have another contex here. I tried this but doesn't  seem to work:             List<string> wordslist = System.IO.File.ReadLines(@"C:\Users\etc\brit.txt").ToList();
            
            wordslist.ForEach(c => context.Anagrams.AddOrUpdate(p => p.Name));
            context.SaveChanges();